# SQL Server PATINDEX returning a value when it shouldn't

Tags: sql-server, patindex

Azure SQL Server 2017

`Status` Field Value:

```
1796-NM_IndiatimesMumbai_Daily has run
```

Statement:

`PATINDEX('%[MED]%', Status COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)`

Returns

`7`

Why?  I thought I was looking for an exact match on "MED" in all caps, so I would expect 0.  I apparently don't have my pattern syntax correct.

Comment: remove the brackets []

Comment: The SQL Server docs are really, really clear on this.

Comment: the square brackets denote a range or set. As you are just looking for a substring rather than a pattern I would use CHARINDEX anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because like  combined with square brackets [] searches for any character between the brackets. Is you remove the brackets
    Like '%MED%'

It works asyou expect